# Can You Use an Existing Core Data DataModel in a New App?

Tags: xcode, core-data

Is it possible to use an existing Core Data model structure in a new iPhone application or do I have to manually re-create all the entities\attributes?  If so, how do I bring it into the new application?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried copying the xcdatamodeld file along with all models from one app to the other? Also, is this for Mac or iOS?

Comment: +1 You can copy over both the datamodel file and the custom NSManagedObject subclass files (if any) just as you can copy over any source file. I have datamodels and classes that I use in multiple apps all the time.

Comment: This is for an IOS app.  I did copy the datamodel file over, but the code couldn't see the pre-existing entities in the file.